# Open multiple files with different time coordinate length

Tags: python, time-series, netcdf, python-xarray

I have two (more) netCDF files which I want to concatenate on the fly using the `open_mfdataset` function in xarray. If I open them separately using `open_dataset`, the structure printed is the following:

```
Dimensions:  (lat: 103, lon: 241, time: 365)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 5.75 5.771 5.792 5.812 5.833 5.854 5.875 5.896 ...
  * lat      (lat) float64 45.75 45.77 45.79 45.81 45.83 45.85 45.88 45.9 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-01-01 2014-01-02 2014-01-03 ...
Data variables:
    TabsD    (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
```

for the first file, and

```
Dimensions:  (lat: 103, lon: 241, time: 31)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 5.75 5.771 5.792 5.812 5.833 5.854 5.875 5.896 ...
  * lat      (lat) float64 45.75 45.77 45.79 45.81 45.83 45.85 45.87 45.9 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2015-01-01 2015-01-02 2015-01-03 ...
Data variables:
    TabsD    (time, lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
```

for the second. The problem now is this error traceback that I get, when I put the filenames in `flist` and do a `data = xr.open_mfdataset(flist, concat_dim='time', cache=False)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition    2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1591, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1018, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/*/Documents/myfile.py", line 110, in <module>
    data = xr.open_mfdataset(flist, concat_dim='time', cache=False) 
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\api.py", line 514, in open_mfdataset
    combined = auto_combine(datasets, concat_dim=concat_dim, compat=compat)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\combine.py", line 396, in auto_combine
    concatenated = [_auto_concat(ds, dim=dim) for ds in grouped]
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\combine.py", line 396, in <listcomp>
    concatenated = [_auto_concat(ds, dim=dim) for ds in grouped]
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\combine.py", line 332, in _auto_concat
    return concat(datasets, dim=dim)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\combine.py", line 120, in concat
    return f(objs, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\combine.py", line 273, in _dataset_concat
    combined = concat_vars(vars, dim, positions)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py", line 1442, in concat
    return Variable.concat(variables, dim, positions, shortcut)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py", line 998, in concat
    data = duck_array_ops.concatenate(arrays, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\duck_array_ops.py", line 48, in f
    return getattr(module, name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 1871, in concatenate
    raise ValueError("Block shapes do not align")
ValueError: Block shapes do not align
```

I tried already:

- to set `chunks={'time':10}` (30, 40, 100 etc...)
- to set `chunks={'lat':10, 'lon':10}`
- to check if the is a gap between the time spans: no

with basically the same result.

What's the trick here?

Comment: i don't know netcdf, but can't you read the files individually and concatenate the data afterwards?

Comment: This is possible, but actually I have 150 quite big files, so that's why I chose `open_mfdataset`, which relies on the `dask` module which is there for handling the large data amount.

Comment: dask can not concatenate DataSets?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. I actually don't want to dig deeper into dask, from what I understand the concatenation should also work in xarray...

Comment: I suggest using NCO instead for this type of concatenation.  http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Concatenation

Comment: True, this is one option, thank you!...however, I would like to avoid dependencies to the world outside of Python.

Comment: I'm fairly sure `xarray` can do this. Can you confirm that all the files have dims: `lat: 103, lon: 241`?

Comment: Thanks @jhamman, yes, I can confirm they all have the same dimensions. But obviouyls there seems to be a precision problem (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you've described shouldn't happen.

My guess is that some of your files actually have different dimension sizes but you're getting an uninformative error message from dask.

The error message you've described no longer appears in the latest release of dask, so there's also a chance that this behavior has been fixed. Please update to the latest releases of xarray/dask and try again.

Comment: Thanks @shoyer, updating to dask 0.15 indeed made the error disappear. Now the files are combined, however, the dimensions almost double due to a precision problem in the lat/lon. In the representation of the xr.Dataset the floats seems to be the same, but a comparison yields almost only "False". Is there a way in xarray to match the closest numbers?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to open the files individually with `xarray.open_dataset()`, reindex them with `reindex()` or `reindex_like()` (use `method='nearest'`) and then concatenate them manually with `xarray.concat()`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! I'm not sure whether to mark the answer as correct now though or better delete the question, because the actual problem was in my data I fear....;-)